# Sorting Column in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a `ng-grid` that has a column i need to sort.
The column contains values `H` ,`M`, and `L`. I have a drop down box that calls the controller on `ng-change` and passes the value selected by the user. So, I have two questions

Function in controller looks like this

```
$scope.impactOrder=function (opt){
    //Test opt contains value from drop down. ie M H or L
    alert (opt);
}
```

1. How can I call `sortFunc` from another function in controller and change grid.
2. What will be the sort Function.

I previously had written code to implement an ascending filter for the same column. It filters from `H =>M => L`.

it looks like this

```
var result = 1;
var test="HML";
function impSortFn(a, b) {
    a=test.indexOf(a);
    b=test.indexOf(b);
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return result;
}
```

Please help :) thanks

Here is the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TOhDhRYM74k3Qevb57wT?p=preview)
In plunk
If the user select Male from Drop down then he should see only Teachers who are male.

Comment: Just took some time and formatted your question.  Please take more care when asking.    If we are going to spend time helping you, you should spend some time and properly ask your question.

Comment: Please prepare a `plunkr` to show your issue.  I have a base `ng-grid` one you can fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/moZjsnu67nG8RfonjeJ9?p=preview